# change javascript let by html click event

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, ejs

```js
<%- include("partials/header") %>
<p> this is main page</p> 
  
<% let cpp= 6 %>
<%  for (let i=0;i<cpp;i++){ %>
<div class="card">
  <li><%= cards[i].name %></li>
  <li><%= cards[i].price %></li>
  <li><%= cards[i].title %></li>
  <li><%= cards[i].inStore %></li>
  <li><%= cards[i].code %></li>
</div>
<% } %>
<div>button id="next">load more</button></div>

<%- include("partials/footer") %>
```

how I can change let `cpp=6` to `cpp=12` on clicking button id="next"

Comment: Please, learn about the [LI Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li) - DIV cannot wrap LI elements. HTML basics.

Comment: In the title you have *"change javascript let"* but somehow you forgot to include any JS that you tried. Please read [ask], then [edit] with a [mcve]. EJS is not helpful. Learn how to use Developer Tools, Inspect Element, and use the generated sample instead of untranspiled EJS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array `cards` must come from the `res.render` statement in your Javascript file, because there is no `let cards`.

```js
res.render("ejsfile", {cards: [...]});
```

So the solution is to put the `cpp` integer there as well and omit the `let cpp = 6` statement:

```js
res.render("ejsfile", {
  cards: [...],
  cpp: Number(req.query.cpp) || 6 // default value
});
```

Then the first 6 entries would be available at `http://server/mainpage?cpp=6` (and also at `http://server/mainpage`, because 6 is the default value). And the "next" button must link to `http://server/mainpage?cpp=12`.

See the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query) for `req.query`.

Comment: it work but i don't understand it ,  can u pls provide me some docs links related to it

Comment: See the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query) for `req.query`.